# Simple SQL Insert with Powershell Invoke Command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

Trying to run a logon script on a domain controlled computer through group policy.  Works great on the Server with SQLserver module installed, but when converting code to use invoke-command and run from domain controlled computer, input into database is empty -- it changes from null to empty.

Code that works:

```
$var1 = $env:xxx
$var2 = $env:xxx
$var3 = $env:xxx

invoke-sqlcmd -Query "insert into tblxxx (abc, def, ghi) values('$var1', '$var2', '$var3')" -connectionstring <connectionstring>
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
$var1 = $env:xxx
$var2 = $env:xxx
$var3 = $env:xxx

invoke-command -computername <server> {invoke-sqlcmd -Query <same query as above> -connectionstring <connectionstring>}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$using:var1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables) inside the `Invoke-Command` because the variable `$var1` is not known in the new scope.

Comment: Do I leave the apostrophe's around $using:var1 -- '$using:var1'?  If I do, its still empty on input, if I take out the apostrophe's I get "invalid column name" and what the variable is set to -- so at least its reading the variable now but not inputting into the database...

Comment: My test only mentioned in my comment above was only using 1 input column causing the issue -- this works thank you!